# jquery content slider sliding

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is the html part of the sliders navigation:

```
<div id="button">
     <a class="button1 active" rel="1" href="#"></a>
     <a class="button2" rel="2" href="#"></a>
     <a class="button3" rel="3" href="#"></a>
</div>
```

This is the complete jQuery code for the slider:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
  $('#button a').click(function(){
    var integer = $(this).attr('rel');
    /*----- Width of div mystuff (here 160) ------ */
    $('#myslide .cover').animate({left:-160*(parseInt(integer)-1)})
    $('#button a').each(function(){
      $(this).removeClass('active');
      if($(this).hasClass('button'+integer)){
        $(this).addClass('active')
      }
    });
  });   
});
```

i am building a content slider for an assignment on college and I am having trouble following this code.

You can find the complete code for this slider [here](http://www.webdeveloperjuice.com/2010/01/12/lightest-jquery-content-slider-ever-made-380-bytes/).

Our 3 links have rel attributes with values 1,2 and 3. This line of jQuery calculates how much will the slider slide:

```
$('#myslide .cover').animate({left:-160*(parseInt(integer)-1)})
```

So if the variable integer is 1 it will be `-160*(1-1)=0` - the slider doesn't move 
if its 2 the result will be -160 and it will move to the right for 160px.
And if its 3 it will move to the right for 320px.

How does this code moves the slide to the left?
It works if you test the demo on the page, but I don't understand how?
Can someone explain it to me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Negative left values will cause the element to move to the left of the 0 position. When you animate from 0 to -160, it will move left.

http://jsfiddle.net/vrRfu/

Am I misunderstanding the question?

[image]

A positive integer multiplied by -160 results in a negative left position causing the element to move left.

Comment: i dont understand is how they move to the left if the integer variable can at any time be only 1,2 or 3?

Comment: If the integer is 1, the left position will be 0. If the integer is 2, the left position will be -160. If the integer is 3, the left position will be -320. Those negative left positions will cause it to go left of it's start position.

Comment: Since you are only doing a horizontal change in position, the graph at the link below demonstrates what is happening. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Number-line.gif

Answer (score 0):

The secret in this slides is the '', cause you have to put the three paragraphs in the same line but make the div the size of only one, when you change the 'overflow' property to hidden all the stuff that is out of the  will disappera so it is like a window which only lñet you see the thing that are infront, and finally with the '.animate()' method you can move things to be infront of the "window"

Comment: I understand how the divs are shown using the overflow:hidden but what i dont understand is how they move to the left if the integer variable can at any time be only 1,2 or 3?

Comment: you are subtracting one and multiplying it with the pargraph width, so when integer=1 left=-160*(1-1)=0, so in the first position there is no move to the left, integer=2 left=-160(2-1)=160, that move the entire block of paragraphs 160 pixels to the left which make the animation change to the second paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

If your integer is 1 and you are moving it to the left, your formula would be (-160)*-1-1, which would give you -320 (moving the slider to the left). If it is positive you would be multiplying by a positive number, moving the slider the the right direction.

Hope that helps.